# SiteFinity if user logged in

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity

I am new to SiteFinity.  This is the first time I have ever seen it.

I am trying to find out how to check to see if the user is logged in and if they are, do not load certain javascript files (we have a conflict that is causing problems with sitefinity's page editor)

So in the header I want to do something like

if(user_logged_in())
     ... load js file here

Also I am trying to do this in the master template files.

Version 6.1 FYI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
ClaimsManager.GetCurrentIdentity().IsAuthenticated
```

This will return whether or not the user is logged in but it sounds like you need to know if they are a backend user so maybe try:

```
ClaimsManager.GetCurrentIdentity().IsBackendUser
```

You'll need this using directive:

```
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work for you. If the user is authenticated it will load you your .js file.

```
var isValidUser = SecurityManager.AuthenticateUser(UserManager.GetDefaultProviderName(), userName, userPassword, true);
if (isValidUser == UserLoggingReason.Success){
   JavaScriptEmbedControl scriptToEmbed = new JavaScriptEmbedControl();
   scriptToEmbed.Url = "path-to-file.js";
   scriptToEmbed.ScriptEmbedPosition = Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.PublicControls.Enums.ScriptEmbedPosition.InPlace;
   this.form1.Controls.Add(scriptToEmbed);
}
```